# Clicking on image in an asp. Net web forms page

Tags: asp.net, image, draw

I have a asp. Net web forms application which displays an image to the user. The image is displayed as an image control. I want the user to click on two different spots on the picture. I want to retrieve the positions where these events take place, and draw a line between the points. How can I add mouse event handles to any control, and specifically an image control?

Can I do seething like this:

```
Image.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.myEventHandler);
```

Comment: Look at using an imagemap instead as it's made to have clickable regions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagemap?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: An ImageButton will tell you where it was clicked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456785/asp-net-image-button-does-not-have-an-onclick-event

Comment: Is there a way to zoom in or out of the image displayed on imagebutton? I need this feature incase the image is big. In a winform program I had, I was displaying images of size 7200x4800